# WordPress posts with custom status need to show in All view

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type

I've built a WooCommerce plugin with a particular feature that stopped working right after I upgraded WordPress from 3.8 to 4.1 and WooCommerce from 1 to 2.2. I had added the dg_order post type, which is similar to the WooCommerce shop_order and shares statuses (processing, completed, etc.). My problem is on the admin table for the posts. Right now, the status views at the top of the table read "All (14) | Completed (14)". However, I see "No DG Orders found" under All. Completed does show the orders appropriately. Here's the post type definition:

```
function dm_inv_dg_post_type () {
    $show_in_menu = current_user_can( 'manage_woocommerce' ) ? 'woocommerce' : true;

    register_post_type( "dg_order", array(
            'labels' => array(
                    'name'                  => __( 'DG Orders', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'singular_name'         => __( 'DG Order', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'add_new'               => __( 'Add Order', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New DG Order', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'edit'                  => __( 'Edit', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Order', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'new_item'              => __( 'New DG Order', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'view'                  => __( 'View Order', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'view_item'             => __( 'View Order', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'search_items'          => __( 'Search DG Orders', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'not_found'             => __( 'No DG Orders found', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No DG Orders found in trash', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'parent'                => __( 'Parent Orders', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'menu_name'             => _x('DG Orders', 'Admin menu name', 'woocommerce')
                ),
            'description'           => __( 'This is where orders to DG are stored.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'public'                => false,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'capability_type'       => 'shop_order',  
            'map_meta_cap'          => true,
            'publicly_queryable'    => false,
            'exclude_from_search'   => true,
            'show_in_menu'          => $show_in_menu,
            'hierarchical'          => false,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
            'rewrite'               => false,
            'query_var'             => false,
            'supports'              => array( 'title', 'comments' ),
            'has_archive'           => false,
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'dm_inv_dg_post_type', 12);
```

The WooCommerce upgrade changed how the statuses are stored (as an actual post status instead of taxonomy terms), so that likely has something to do with it. I thought it might have something to do with the `show_in_admin_all_list` parameter for `register_post_status`, but the WooCommerce developers set that to `true`, and the correct number of completed orders show up in the All count.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That's quite an update! Why not update to WC 2.3 and troubleshoot from there? What exactly is your plugin supposed to do?

Comment: Big plugin, one developer, and not enough time. I released the plugin to the target audience with this bug. I know it will take me a while to work out the kinks with 2.3, and I'd like to fix this problem before I take that time. ** The plugin provides a link from WooCommerce to a certain (name withheld) wholesaler, so that when a customer make an order, the order may be automagically transferred to the wholesaler.